# Azure Function dependencies

Tags: azure-functions

I am developing a number of Functions using Visual Studio. I would like to take advantage of the fixed delay retry to have different retires per function:
[FixedDelayRetry(5, "00:00:10")]

This requires Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs v2.0.23 which requires Newtonsoft.Json v11.0.2. My project is currently in .Net Framework using Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions v1.0.38 which has a dependency on Newtonsoft.Json v9.0.1.

Am I right in thinking that because I am using .Net Framework I can't upgrade Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions to v3.x?

If I upgrade Newtonsoft.Json to v11.0.2 on my project and add Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs v2.0.23 I get a package version outside of dependency constraint for NewtonsoftJson - should I be concerned about this?

Thanks
Paul

Answer (score 1):

> Am I right in thinking that because I am using .Net Framework I can't
> upgrade Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions to v3.x?

Yes, you are right.

And azure function package is a package collection in fact. If you install the high level package, the older package will be covered. So use high level package may cause unforeseen problem.